# Guidance for "reference architecture" for thin-thick native app

Tags: architecture

I'd be really grateful for some guidance from anyone with suggestions regarding best architecture for a "thin-thick native app" which can run on Windows and OSX (Linux Ubuntu too would be a bonus).

See the outline of what I'm thinking below in the image - I'm actually a data scientist working in Python building and operationalising various analytics models through API's (falcon, flask, waitress, gunicorn) but am keen on building a desktop application (for a change) which can be more easily maintained than a traditional "thick native application".

[image: Rough Architecture]

Essentially what would be first prize would be a "reference architecture" for having three layers of the "desktop app" - essentially a thin front-end (coded as a native app, with very little code inside this component itself) that connects to the "server" and "database" layers (also local).

The server layer is where I would like most of the intelligence / code to happen - and make it easily maintainable. Ideally I would like this server layer to be in a language that doesn't require lots of separate code for the two different OS's - and naturally Python would be first prize given my history with it if possible (Django might work for server?), but I'm also very willing to learn anything else that might be more suitable.

Some bespoke coding for the thin native client would be perfectly acceptable, if it is mostly around providing the "web client" itself - i.e. pretty much just a browser with some additional functionality.

I would be grateful for any recommendations for anything I could check out especially as a whole where something similar is already done, or recommendations for the various layers.

I hope the question is clear - thanks and all the best!

Comment: Technologies you can look into: golang has compilers for many platforms and container technology can help as well (bringing its own OS where required). Also some concerns about a local web stack: Using a local server comes with installing a local server, that may be a security concern in many professional settings and you'll have to make sure to only allow local connections. The same is true for a local DB and both also come with potential service port conflicts. Why can't you move the backend to the cloud? That would also enable it for mobile use, e.g. tablets.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Oswin. Makes sense - appreciate it, and will definitely look into golang. Cloud first design would be great, but from a data perspective I expect the users would prefer to have local storage, with a cloud sync option, rather than having their data in the cloud by default (even though cloud is probably more secure anyway).